# Fluent NHibernate automapper: skip an intermediate class w/ table-per-subclass

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, automapping

I'm using the Fluent NHibernate mapper with table-per-subclass to map the following structure:

```
public abstract class A
{
    // properties here
}

public abstract class B : A
{
    // methods here
}

public class C : B
{
    // properties here
}
```

My database only has tables to represent class `A` and class `C`. Class `B` exists only in my model for my convenience and doesn't contain any properties that needs to be mapped.

How can I get the automapper to skip `B` and map `C` as a subclass of `A`?

Comment: Seeing your mapping overrides or manual class maps would be helpful. Also, can you post your initialization where you have the IncludeBase<A> code?

Comment: I'm using the automapper and I don't have any manual maps or overrides at the moment.

Comment: FYI, the issue I opened relating to your question has now been resolved. The only thing you need to be aware of for this particular situation is that abstract classes are deemed [layer supertypes](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/layerSupertype.html) by default, so your `A` class wouldn't get mapped unless you used `IncludeBase<A>` explicitly or overrode the `AbstractClassIsLayerSupertype` configuration method to exclude that class.

Comment: Thanks! Glad for the follow up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Fluent NHibernate wiki](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org) has a section on [ignoring base types when automapping](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Auto_mapping#Ignoring_base-types) that might be worth reading.

Comment: If you skip the intermediate subclass with IgnoreBase as the wiki article suggests, then believes class `C` is an independent class unrelated to `A`.

Comment: Ah, bummer. That'll be a bug then. I've created an issue for you to track: http://fluentnhibernate.lighthouseapp.com/projects/33236-core/tickets/128-skip-intermediary-classes-when-automapping-subclasses.

Comment: Links are dead. I think this is the current version: https://github.com/nhibernate/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Auto-mapping-generic-base-classes